# System Notifications For Users with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, notifications

I've seen lots of various posts on SO regarding notification systems for users, (e.g., a user comments on a picture, sends a message, etc...).

I am curious how to put together "system notifications" that would be generated by the website administrator.  These could be messages that are displayed to *every* user upon login, such as:

1) Reminders for system maintenance/downtime
2) Notice of upcoming changes
3) Any other messages that need to be displayed system-wide

What is a good way to do this?  I would like these messages to be displayed for all users, and users would have the opportunity to "hide" (thus, marking it as "read") it so it doesn't show up again when they login later.  Is this something that should be done database-side, with sessions, or both?

Any ideas on how to get this started would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add a notification table with m:n to users and a read column (tinyint 0 or 1), show it within your template if read is 0 and update the row to 1 on click. I guess I don't unterstand the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a notification table consisting of a msgID, message, creationTime, expirationTime. Then a users table such as userNotifications which would consist of userID, msgID.

When they, the user, flag a message as dismissed, add the msg id to the userNotifications. This lets you build queries for all notifications that are not expired and have also not been dismissed by the user.

Comment: Or you could create a cookie that holds a boolean value with the message ID and if the user has hid it; read it with PHP and if it's set don't generate the notification on the page.

Comment: @scjosh and if he login at home, at school, at work, in the airport, at the mcdonald, he will still get the notification and its annoying... mysql is the way to go.